# About ggplot titles inside a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a function below,

```
create_plot <- function(variable) {
 return(qplot(data = white_wine, x = variable ,color =I('black'),fill = 
        qual_factor ))+
      ggtitle('Distribution of quality with respect to _______')}
```

Below I am calling the function with two different variables:

```
create_plot(white_wine$total.sulfur.dioxide)

create_plot(white_wine$density)
```

I have put "_______" in ggtitle syntax , because I want the name of any variable that I call.

For example ,

```
'enter code hereDistribution of quality with respect to total.sulfur.dioxide' when 
     white_wine$total.sulfur.dioxide is called, and ,'Distribution of quality with respect to density' when white_wine$density is called.
```

Comment: why not add a second argument to the function where you define the name to be put in the title? then use `paste`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use another argument in your function call ?

```
create_plot <- function(variable, title) {
 return(qplot(data = white_wine, x = variable ,color =I('black'),fill = 
        qual_factor ))+
      ggtitle(paste0('Distribution of quality with respect to ', title))}

create_plot(white_wine$total.sulfur.dioxide, 'total sulfure dioxine')

create_plot(white_wine$density, 'density')
```